# How does dplyr handle empty groups when displaying "groups" attribute?

Tags: r, dplyr

Taking an example from the dplyr tests:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  e = 1,
  f = factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2), levels = 1:3),
  g = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  x = c(1, 2, 1, 4)
) %>%
  group_by(e, f, g, .drop = FALSE)
```

I don't quite understand why or how the `"groups"` attribute is defined as such

```r
attr(df, "groups")
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#       e f         g       .rows
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <list<int>>
# 1     1 1         1         [2]
# 2     1 2         2         [2]
# 3     1 3        NA         [0]
```

The third row doesn't make any sense to me, it's not a valid group within the original data. I'd have thought the result would be:

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#       e f         g       .rows
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <list<int>>
# 1     1 1         1         [2]
# 2     1 2         2         [2]
# 3    NA 3        NA         [0]
```

Comment: There is only one value for 'e' and it can get recycled while for 'g' there is 2 and it is still short of 1 with the max levels of 'f'.  So, it is NA appended

Comment: That's the only viable option that I can think of. But this isn't documented anywhere and I certainly wouldn't "expect" it otherwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248086/r-dplyrs-group-by-consider-empty-groups-as-well>

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely due to recycling.  It occurs in many functions

```
 data.frame(e = 1, b = c(2, 4), c = c(2, 3, 2, 4))
```

Here, the e value of 1 and 'b' values gets recycled.  May be in the group attributes, the recycling happens only when there is a single unique value

Comment: This can be seen when comparing `.drop = FALSE` with `.drop = TRUE`.

Comment: Yes, the tidyverse recylcing rule is: "(only) vectors of length 1 are recycled to any other size" (including length 0) - see the discussion [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/design/issues/13).